# Why occured Exception: Fragment not attached to a context

Tags: android, kotlin

I create Fragment named HomeFragment.

And write code that show DialogFragment in Fragment(HomeFragment) below

```
private fun showCustomDialog() {
    CustomDialog().apply {
        arguments = Bundle().apply {
            putString("title", requireContext().getString(R.string.app_name))
        }
    }.show(parentFragmentManager, "customDialog")
}
```

When I used `requireContext()` to get title in `Bundle().apply`, Exception occured like below

```
Fragment CustomDialog{1ef2304} (4ca006b2-19b7-4550-a227-e5c6d1d43e02) not attached to a context.
```

On the other hand, Exception not occured when I used `this@HomeFragment` instead of using `requireContext()`

```
private fun showCustomDialog() {
    CustomDialog().apply {
        arguments = Bundle().apply {
            // Exception not occured
            putString("title", this@HomeFragment.getString(R.string.app_name))
        }
    }.show(parentFragmentManager, "customDialog")
}
```

using `requireContext()` is that context is null, Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `CustomDialog` is a `Fragment` and `requireContext()` resolves to your `CustomDialog` instead of the containing `HomeFragment` due to the `apply` scope function. After instantiating the dialog fragment it is not yet attached to any context, so `requireContext()` will throw.